# Google Analytics Track Order not visible and not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, joomla, google-analytics

When i run this code on google chrome its 
not working and not view in page view source and i am not able to track the order while this code is working and visible in page view source on Firefox and i can track the order on google  analytics dashboard.

So, please suggest me where i am doing wrong. Code are given below.

Thanks in advance.

```js
**********eCommerce Tracking Sample Code*********

<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[‘GoogleAnalyticsObject’]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,’script’,’//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js’,’ga’);

ga(‘create’, ‘UA-XXXXXX-12’, ‘auto’);

ga(‘require’, ‘ecommerce’, ‘ecommerce.js’);

ga(‘ecommerce:addTransaction’, {
‘id’: ‘1234’, // Transaction ID. Required.
‘affiliation’: ‘skinny jeans’, // store name.
‘revenue’: ‘28.8’, // total revenue.
‘shipping’: ‘10.00’, // Shipping.
‘tax’: ‘1.89’ // Tax.
});

ga(‘ecommerce:addItem’, {
‘id’: ‘1234’, // Transaction ID. Required. Same as in the transaction data.
‘name’: ‘OKEJeans’, // Product name. Required.
‘sku’: ‘SKJ49’, // Product SKU.
‘category’: ‘Men Jeans’, // Product Category or variation.
‘price’: ‘76.65’, // Product price.
‘quantity’: ‘1’ // Product Quantity.
});

ga(‘ecommerce:send’);

ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’);

</script>
```

Comment: Code works fine for me with chrome (your example uses curvy quotes, I assume that's an effect of copy & paste and replaced them for testing). I recommend you test with the GA Debugger extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en and/or the Google Tag Assistant https://get.google.com/tagassistant/ and look if an error message shows up. Based on the code alone I do not think it is possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has incorrect quotes and reversed order of transaction and items.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-12', 'auto');

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');


ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '1234', // Transaction ID. Required. Same as in the transaction data.
'name': 'OKEJeans', // Product name. Required.
'sku': 'SKJ49', // Product SKU.
'category': 'Men Jeans', // Product Category or variation.
'price': '76.65', // Product price.
'quantity': '1' // Product Quantity.
});

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '1234', // Transaction ID. Required.
'affiliation': 'skinny jeans', // store name.
'revenue': '28.8', // total revenue.
'shipping': '10.00', // Shipping.
'tax': '1.89' // Tax.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

It seems to work.

[image]